# VisualStateManager.GoToState doesn't work when I call it in DependencyProperty

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I create an DependencyProperty (for example: MyEffect) and use this property for my textbox.

```
<TextBox Grid.Row="0" x:Name="MyTextBox"                        
                        Text ="{Binding Model.MyValue}"                             
                        behaviors:MyEffect="{Binding EffectSample}">
</TextBox>
```

In PropertyChangedCallback function, I call

```
myControl.SetValue(TextBox.TextProperty, "Hello");
VisualStateManager.GoToState(myControl, "InvalidFocused", true);
```

my textbox display "Hello" but Its State doesn't change to InvalidFocused. So How can I change state of my textbox ?

Answer (score 0):

This is off the top of my head but it may be the type you are passing to the GotToState method. It's expecting a Control so I would do the following, assuming myControl is being passed in as a DependencyProperty.

`var control = myControl as Control;

VisualStateManager.GoToState(myControl, "InvalidFocused", true);`